# why does the JTextField go beyond the border of the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

Good evening.
I'm having a strange problem with the JTextField in my gui for a calculator.
in few word the Text field goes beyond the border of the frame (which is 500), the strange thing is that i've set the lenght bound of the text field as the lenght of the frame (0,0, **500**, 50).

this is the code:

```
package calcolatrice;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Calcolatrice {
 Calcolatrice(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Calculator");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLayout(null);

    JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();
    displayPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    displayPanel.setBounds(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), 50);
    displayPanel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(displayPanel);

    JTextField display = new JTextField("Prova");
    display.setBounds(0, 0, displayPanel.getWidth(), displayPanel.getHeight());
    display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    displayPanel.add(display);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and this is the following output:

[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYu2t.png)

I hope that someone can explain me what is going on with that JTextField and help me solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to cringe every time I see `setLayout(null)` and `.setBounds(...)`. By doing this, you're fighting against the GUI library for no good reason and will run into problems including what you're seeing as well as GUI's that look terrible on other platforms and GUI's that are very difficult to enhance, update and debug. The solution is simple: learn and use the layout managers. Set the JTextField's column property and font if you need to change horizontal or vertical size, not its bounds.

Comment: Solution: put the JTextField into the `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` (or NORTH) position of a JPanel that uses a `BorderLayout`.

Comment: Or just add the text field directly to the frame, since by default it uses a BorderLayout (there is no need for the panel, since the content pane of the frame actually is a JPanel anyway).

Comment: *I hope that someone can explain me what is going on with that JTextField* - how could the text field be the same size as the frame if the frame also has "borders". The borders are included in the frame size so any component added to the frame must be smaller than the frame. That is why you use a layout manager. It does the calculations for you.